How do I fix this error: Query data cannot be undefined. Please make sure to return a value other than undefined from your query function
I have the following code.
import Post from "../post/Post";
import "./posts.scss";
import {useQuery} from "@tanstack/react-query";
import {makeRequest} from "../../axios";

//omitted code here

        const {isLoading, error, data } =  useQuery({
          queryKey: ["posts"],
          queryFn: () => {
           makeRequest.get("/posts").then((res) => {
            return res.data;
           })
          },
        });

In the browser I am getting the following error:
Query data cannot be undefined. Please make sure to return a value other than undefined from your query function. Affected query key: ["posts"]

maybe return res.data??[];

@aloMalbarez i tried that but doesnt seem to work.

You cant really fix it as data can always be undefined because before the promise resolves, data will always be undefined.
The only real way you can fix it is to give a default value to data
const {isLoading, error, data = [] } =  useQuery({
    queryKey: ["posts"],
    queryFn: () => {
        makeRequest.get("/posts").then((res) => {
            return res.data;
        })
    },
});

Though this isn't the best way to do it as data would always be an empty array, even if there is an error.
What would probably be better is build out your component like this
const Component = () => {
  const {isLoading, isError, data } =  useQuery({
    queryKey: ["posts"],
    queryFn: () => {
        makeRequest.get("/posts").then((res) => {
            return res.data;
        })
    },
  });

  if(isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>
  if(isError || !data) return <div>Something went wrong</div>

  // data will now always be defined 
  return ...
}



queryFn should return the promise.
 const {isLoading, error, data } =  useQuery({
          queryKey: ["posts"],
          queryFn: () => {
           return makeRequest.get("/posts");
          },
        });


I'm very new to react. I'm not sure what that means. Can you provide an example?

this doesnt solve the issue, yes queryFn should return a promise but until that promise is resolved data will be undefined
